# Почему Дух сообщества не ищется на странице участников на мете?

Tags: дефект, мета, дух-сообщества, страница-участников

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не воспроизводится: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIsks.png

Comment: @АндрейNOP обновил вопрос. Оказывается, только на мете не ищется. Вдвойне странно (:

Comment: На других сайтах такая же история, рекомендую на MSE вынести.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324038/260198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он виден только на вкладке, где сортировка по репутации. На мете просто этого таба нет. Но если зайти напрямую, то Дух находится: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему *Он виден только на вкладке, где сортировка по репутации*? Это разве нормальное поведение?

Comment: @АндрейNOP насколько я понял, да. Мол, он на вкладке правок и голосов будет в топе, что смущало бы участников.